# Querying partial value from a field - SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to return only a portion of the value in a given field.

Example:

A given field returns something like 'AB-1X3.4567' but the desired value is only the '1X3.4567'portion.  So for this example I need to remove anything that precedes the pattern of

```
[0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][.][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z].
```

What query could I write to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `stuff()` and `patindex()`:

```
create table t (val varchar(32))
insert into t values 
 ('AB-1X3.4567') -- given example
,('1X3.4567AB-1X3.4567') --extra junk on the end
,('1X3.4567')     -- goldy locks
,('X3.4567')      -- too short
,('AB-1X#.4567')  -- # is not [0-9A-Z]

select 
    val
  , str = stuff(val,1,patindex('%[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][.][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]%',val)-1,'')
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ITUJ68634

returns:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|         val         |         str         |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| AB-1X3.4567         | 1X3.4567            |
| 1X3.4567AB-1X3.4567 | 1X3.4567AB-1X3.4567 |
| 1X3.4567            | 1X3.4567            |
| X3.4567             | NULL                |
| AB-1X#.4567         | NULL                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: More dynamic solution than mine. i was working on this before you posted-- 1 from me.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, both answers were helpful. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern alludes to anything which is XXX.XXXX where X = any single digit or letter. In that case we can use `RIGHT()` and `LEN()`

```
 DECLARE @value VARCHAR(4000)='AB-1X3.4567'

 SELECT RIGHT(@value,LEN(@value) - 3)
```